Installing private GO module in ADO pipeline without using secrets
I want to install a private go module without using ssh key, PAT token or github OAuth token. This private github repo belongs to me and I can successfully checkout in the repo using service connection in ADO pipeline, but i am not able to install the repo as a go module as it is asking for github authentication. Clusterfleet is the private module that needs to be installed.
Is there any way to do it?
resources:
  - repository: Clusterfleet
    type: github
    endpoint: "Falcon (1)"
    name: webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet
    ref: refs/tags/v0.2.7

I tried making a local clusterfleet package and force the pipeline to use the local package with go.work file.
- script: |
            # Set GOPATH to include the pipeline workspace
            export GOPATH=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/go
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GOPATH]$GOPATH"

            # Add the Clusterfleet module to GOPATH
            mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/webxt-microsoft
            ln -s $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/clusterfleet $GOPATH/src/github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet

            # Set GOPRIVATE to include github.com/webxt-microsoft
            go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/webxt-microsoft

            # Update Go module cache
            cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet
            go mod download
          displayName: 'Setup Clusterfleet module'

- script: |
            echo "Creating go.work file"
            cat << EOF > $(Pipeline.Workspace)/go.work
            go 1.21

            use (
                $(GOPATH)/src/github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet
            )
            EOF
            cat $(Pipeline.Workspace)/go.work
          displayName: 'Create go.work file'

But it is not working and throws the following error:
go: github.com/webxt-microsoft/falconfleet/cmd/apiserverproxy/app/run imports
github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet/pkg/client/clientset/versioned: reading github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet/go.mod at revision v0.2.7: git ls-remote -q origin in /mnt/vss/_work/1/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cdbe37fa44eec61731b059b590c47e1b60a2c549f9a741905e85b859212d994b: exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.

Replacing the remote path to local path of the module worked for me.
go mod edit -replace github.com/webxt-microsoft/clusterfleet=../clusterfleet

